# Default assembly binding behaviour

Tags: c#, assemblies, assemblybinding

We are building an API  that is stored in an assembly, let's call it MyAssembly.dll

This assembly has an AssemblyVersion of 1.0.0.0

I would expect, that when releasing a new version of the assembly, previous code that compiled referencing to 1.0.0.0 version would break, since the assembly binding would fail (without some extra help like bindRedirect).

In practice, what i see is is the binding actually succeeds.

I have tested it by building a MyAssembly.dll with various different versions, and trying to run various code that was referencing 1.0.0.0

Is this the default behaviour? Does binding to the *EXACT* version occur only from strong-name (signed) assemblies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How the runtime locates assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

"By default, the runtime attempts to bind with the exact version of an assembly that the application was built with. This default behavior can be overridden by configuration file settings."

(...)

"Note: There is no version checking for assemblies without strong names, nor does the runtime check in the global assembly cache for assemblies without strong names."

Comment: Excellent! Is there any rule of thumb regarding when to place assemblies in the GAC or not?

Comment: @liortal: There's almost nothing SO hasn't discussed before :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451123/when-should-i-deploy-my-assemblies-into-the-gac