# deploy application dependencies to program folder or GAC

Tags: c#, .net, windows, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I deploy my assemblies into the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451123/when-should-i-deploy-my-assemblies-into-the-gac)

How do you deploy your applications?

- copy all necessary DLLs (your own, 3rd party, etc.) into the application folder and be finished

**or**

- deploy some or all dependent DLLs to the GAC

**Is there a *best practice* which of the above solutions to use and which DLLs go into the application folder vs GAC?**

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451123/when-should-i-deploy-my-assemblies-into-the-gac which answers my question

Comment: The basic rule is **not** to deploy to the GAC. It's *extremely rare* that you ever have a need to deploy to the GAC. Always use the program folder, or a common program folder shared by multiple applications. (Yeah, good, glad to see the linked question you found actually *has* that answer. There's a lot of bad advice floating around about this.)

Answer (score -1):

I am using ClickOnce. So, I do not worry about versioning, GAC and other stuff, i just create additional folders in project solutions to copy 3-d party assemblies into, and do not have any of difficulties with updates, besause it is very easy to implement custom update system using built-in update system and reflection (for custom versioning), you can easily find this information about ClickIOnce deployment and custom updates

for simplicity, i recommend to use this directory structure:

```
<assembly set>\<assembly name>\<assembly version>\
```

For example:

media\ui\1.0.0.0\ui.dll

or

assemblies\libvnc\1.11.10\libvnc.dll

Comment: So you're recommending that he switch to ClickOnce instead of answering his actual question?