# asp.net web api system dlls in GAC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, gac

When I create ASP.NET Web API project, it references all system dlls which are stored in packages folder.  When I deploy it to production environment, can I drop those dlls in GAC?  I don't know why those system dlls not installed in GAC already when I stall asp.net MVC 4.  Are they moving away installing DLLs in GAC?

Answer (score 0):

No, do not deploy those DLLs to the GAC.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451201/48082

Deploy those DLLs to your app bin directory.