# How to install assemblies in both specific folders and in the GAC

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I created an installer and need to install dll files on a client PC. What would I need to do in the installer so that the dll files are placed in a in specific folder and GAC as well.

For Example,

```
Program Files
 Hello World
  Hello.dll

Windows
 assembly
  Hello.dll
```

Comment: Why would you do that? If you have the file installed in the GAC - the assembly is accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create two separate components. On the [File Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html) of the component you wish to install in the GAC you will need to add the Assembly attribute and set it to ".net"

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite a while since I deployed things into the GAC. **Rick's advice is technically sound**, but please check the following thread for **some conceptual considerations** for when GAC deployment is appropriate:

**[When should I deploy my assemblies into the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451123/when-should-i-deploy-my-assemblies-into-the-gac)**